# Processing: delay only runs once in a thread

Tags: java, delay, processing

So within my processing script I call for a function to give me a random number between 1 and 2.

Since I need the delay to be separate from the main script I call it within a thread, but when it hits a delay it only delays the thread once.

Then when it loops but proceeds to skips the delay command.

How would I change my script to allow the thread to endlessly repeat while waiting 5 seconds in between running the random command?

```
void timeFunction(){ 
  Delay(5000);
  Quickswitch = random(1, 2);
  thread("Timefunction");
}
```

Comment: use a boolean flag. set it first time and inspect every time.

Comment: "but when it hits a delay it only delays the thread once."

"Then when it loops but proceeds to skips the delay command." I don't understand, please post more code to show your point.